# Draw line within Text Object in Crystal Object?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have a text object which has two fields in it which I'm populating from my database.
I need to insert a line between these two fields of the text object.
Field 1 has a possibility of growing , so for that I have checked the Can Grow property.
How can I achieve this. I cannot add a line within a text object.

Answer (score 1):

If both of that objects are in the same text object and lengths can variable of both text fields, then you should have similar syntax in your text object `{firstField} {secondField}` (separated by space).

Output of that field can be :

```
Foo Fooooooooooooooo
Foooooooooooooooo Foo
etc.
```

To separate them just put some delimiter in the middle like `{firstField} / {secondField}` or `{firstField} | {secondField}` and then you will always see

```
Foo / Fooooooooooooooo
Foooooooooooooooo | Foo
etc.
```

Your thinking about drawing a line is hard because when text object can grow, line don't take care of that, and you then draw a line on your text.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Create two sections. Put a line object in between them. Now place one of the field in the top section and another in the bottom section. Also check Keep Together checkbox. So that both lines place together.